# Ruby on Rails2.3.8: How do I run a test using the dev environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

My test env is doing something that doesn't happen in dev. So, if I could run the tests in the dev env, then that would meat that there is something wrong with my tests (if they still fail), or the test env is broke (if they don't fail)

currently, I'm running single functional tests by doing

```
ruby /path/to/test_controller_test.rb
```

Comment: What specifically is happening in the test environment that is not happening in dev?  You probably shouldn't run your tests against the dev environment.  I'm fairly sure it's hard-coded to the test environment anyway.  Explain the actual issue and we might be able to identify why there's a difference and make some changes to avoid it happening in future.

Comment: I'm trying to test the destroy method. which is the exact same between two controllers. But in the test environment, one controller's destroy works, and teh other one doesn't.  by works, I mean, if the user has permission to delete, it deletes, and errors otherwise. but in the test environment, it always deletes.

Comment: I agree w/ d11wtq.  I would put your cycles into your tests (in the test environment) and figure it out there. I like to use a lot of `puts` statements when my tests are confusing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running individual tests, there's nothing to stop you from taking a snapshot of your `development` database and loading it in to the `test` database. If you run `rake test` then that will get cleared out, so keep that in mind.

You may have tests that depend on records that don't exist, usually the result of making unsafe assumptions, or methods that don't work properly when certain things have not been built correctly. It is rare to find that the settings in `config/environments` have any direct effect on the tests themselves.